# Reversing an equation for a sales manager

Tags: quadratics

I need to make a guide for a sales manager letting him know what the lowest he is allowed to sell a product for based on the quantity of the sale.

Right now I can only think of a cumbersome equation, as follows:

```
(([sale price]-[cost])-([sale price]*0.05))*[sale quantity]=[profit], profit must be equal to or above 0.66*[sale quantity]
```

In order to effectively use this equation, the sales manager will have to guess what the lowest price is, run the equation, then see if it is equal to 0.66*[quantity]. Is there an equation that will allow him to find the sales price that will return a profit of exactly 0.66*[quantity]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll use these variables:

$p$ = sale price

$c$ = cost

$q$ = sale quantity

$f$ = profit

Your equation is
$$( (p-c)-(p*0.05))*q = f$$
subject to
$$f \ge 0.66*q$$

So you want to find the smallest $p$ such that
$$( (p-c)-(p*0.05))*q \ge 0.66*q\\
(p-c)-(p*0.05) \ge 0.66\\
p - p*0.05 \ge 0.66 + c\\
0.95*p \ge 0.66 + c\\
p \ge (0.66 + c)/0.95$$

So $(0.66 + c)/0.95$ gives you the lowest price, where c is the cost.

Comment: Thanks, you've answered the question perfectly. Unfortunately I've realised I asked the wrong question...

The equation I wrote basically says that a minimum of 66p per product must be made in order for a sale to go ahead, but I was trying to write an equation that gave him a higher margin if the sale quantity was small and a lower margin if the sale quantity was low. Any idea how I might do that?